# Variable undefined google script for sheets IF Statement

Tags: variables, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
var app = spreadhseetapp;
```

is giving me the error message of "spreadhseetapp" is not defined. How can I fix this?

```
function myFunction() {

  //var app = spreadhseetapp;

  var activesheet = getactivespreadsheet().getactivesheet();

  var workingcell = activesheet.getrange(1, 3).getvalue();

  if(workingcell > 1){

 activesheet.getrange(1, 4).setvalue("Dues Paid");
 }

}
```

[Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_2f4CKd6FfXaIZq0-gYNwvPF9i1Y1ZT8YNTheExjLPQ/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Why you comment spreadhseetapp in program

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {

  //var app = spreadhseetapp;

  var activesheet = getactivespreadsheet().getactivesheet();

  var workingcell = activesheet.getrange(1, 3).getvalue();

  if(workingcell > 1){

 activesheet.getrange(1, 4).setvalue("Dues Paid");
 }

}
```

> Code should be written in case sensitive(eg. functions name) format.
>   Check this below code and check if it works.

```
function myFunction() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;

  var activesheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()

  var workingcell = activesheet.getRange(1, 3).getValue();

  if(workingcell > 1){

 activesheet.getRange(1, 4).setValue("Dues Paid");
 }

}
```

Comment: I tried the above code and it is still giving me this error message "ReferenceError: "spreadsheetapp" is not defined. (line 3, file "Code")

Comment: Please share your sheet link here.